# append li into another li

Tags: jquery, append, html-lists

I have an unordered list with userid attr (i.e. `uid`).

```
<li uid="1">KEY A</li>
<li uid="2">KEY B</li>
<li uid="3">KEY C</li>
<li uid="4">KEY D</li>
<li uid="5">KEY E</li>
<li uid="6">KEY F</li>
```

I'm using jQuery to get the `uid` using `$(this).attr('uid')` and pass it to A page that will look up the `id` and return a value. The code i'm using to send the data is as below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").click(function(){
  var val = $(this).attr("uid");
$.post("tree-process.php",{val:val},function(response){
    alert(response);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

This response value will be in an `ul` like below:

```
<ul>
  <li uid="1">VAL A</li>
  <li uid="2">VAL B</li>
</ul>
```

I need the `ul` response to be inserted inside the clicked `li` such as below :

```
<li uid="1">KEY A</li>
  <ul>
    <li uid="1">VAL A</li>
    <li uid="2">VAL B</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How do I append the response value to the li?

thank you !!

Comment: how you are getting this response? ... if response is html then append it to clicked li.

Comment: pls share your jQuery code or JSfiddle

Comment: Please post your jQuery code as your question is not clear at all

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. i added the jquery code i used. Thank you

Comment: `$(this).append(response);` will append the response to the currently clicked li

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it below

Comment: hi mohamedrias,

i added the $(this).append(response); and it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("li").click(function() {
   var uid =  $(this).attr('uid');
    // pass the uid to the next page and get the response
    var response = functionName(uid);// some function call back to get the <ul> corresponding to that li uid

   // Now add the response which is a ul to the li

     if($(this).find('ul').length===0) {
      $(this).append(response); 
    }
   // insert your response there
});
```

As per your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").click(function(){
  var self = this;
  var val = $(this).attr("uid");
   $.post("tree-process.php",{val:val},function(response){
       if($(self).find('ul').length===0) {
          $(self).append(response);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

**[JSBIN Sample](http://jsbin.com/gaxefu/1/edit)**

Comment: thank you, this worked. how ever, everytime i click, the response will be added constantly. how do i clear the li 1st before appending it?

Comment: Updated the answer.. Please check the above answer. Now before appending am checking if there are any ul already present. If it's not present only then i am appending the ul

Comment: http://jsbin.com/pusadado/3/edit

i tried using your code with the $.post and it works. but when i used $.post to get the response, it still adds the new response li in the parent li. and also, why do i get the parent's uid when i click the child li?

Comment: You need to use event delegation for that. I have updated the code in that jsBIN. Please check it now.

Comment: thank you, 
but when i put it my code, using the $.post .. it doesn't work.

Comment: replace 'this' with 'self' in the $.post function

Comment: hi @mohamedrias, after a lot of fiddling, i finally made it work. thank you for your help :)

Comment: any idea on how how i can made this as a toggle function to show and hide?

Comment: By appending "active" class to the currently clicked li you can extend it. And when you click on any other li, you can remove the active class from previous li and append to the current one

Comment: i think i can do append the "active" class on click, but i'm not sure how to remove the active class from previous li . :(

Comment: how can i put a .toggle() function inside this?

Comment: Please start another question for that, It would be useful to others as well